# python dbf struct.error: unpack requires a string argument of length 4

Tags: python

I have a program that detects changes in dbf a file and uploads it to a mysql database. It was working up till today.

```
Getting struct.error: unpack requires a string argument of length 4
```

I have striped down the code just to iterate over the dbf file yet i still get the same error.

```
import dbf

source_path = "/path/to/file"
file_name = "/file.dbf"


source = dbf.Table(source_path + file_name)
source.open()

for row in source:
    print row
```

Comment: Side note, it is more robust to use [`os.path.join`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.join)`(source_path, file_name)` instead of string concatenation.